# Why polynomial functions f(x)+g(x) = (f+g)(x)?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, notation

Why polynomial functions f(x)+g(x) is the same notation as (f+g)(x)? 
I've seen the sum of polynomials as f(x)+g(x) before, but never seen a notation as with a operator in a prenthesis as (f+g)(x). And author puts (f+g)(x) at the first.

[image]

Source: Linear Algebra and Its Applications, Gareth Williams

> Definition 8. Let X and Y be sets. A function from X to Y is a triple (f, X, Y), where f is a relation from X to Y satisfying
>   (a) Dom(f) = X.
>   (b) If (x, y)$\in f$ and (x, z) $\in f$, then y=z.

"We shall adhere to the custom of writing f: $X\space \rightarrow Y$ instead of (f, X, Y) and $y=f(x)$ instead of $(x,\space y) \in f$."

Source: Set Theory You-Feng Lin, Shwu-Yeng T.Lin

Comment: (f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x) is the definition of the function (f+g). With this definition, polynomials form a vector space.

Comment: If you have trouble understanding this, consider $(f+g)$ as a name, e.g. you could define $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$, only that you use symbol $(f+g)$ instead of $h$. The upside of this is that you need a new definition for any new name like $h$, but it is obvious what $(f+f)$ means or $(g+h)$ or even $(f + (f + g))$.

Answer (score 1):

> Why polynomial functions $f(x)+g(x)$ is the same notation as $\mathsf (f+g\mathsf)(x)$?

Why not?   It is convenient and brief.   It lets us talk about the polynomial $f+g$ .

> I've seen the sum of polynomials as $f(x)+g(x)$ before, but never saw a notation as with a operator in a parenthesis as $\mathsf(f+g\mathsf)(x)$. And author puts $\mathsf(f+g\mathsf)(x)$ at the first.

Well, the author is *defining* the notation; right there.   It just *introduced* you to it.   Shake hands and get to know it.   Now you will know what the author means when it is used in future.

What do you suppose $\mathsf(f+g+h\mathsf)(x)$ means?

For that matter $\mathsf (f\cdot g\mathsf)(x)$ should be introduced soon too.   Can you anticipate what that shall mean?

Comment: As a side note, if this is a first linear algebra text it probably doesn't get into algebras. $f\cdot g$ is unlikely to be defined and if it is defined, it might mean an inner product via an integral or something. In any other intro to rigor text I would agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

This is very practical, as we indicates that f and g are being applied to the same element and it is the usual amount defined in the vector space of continuous functions.